# Using methods in interpolation on the DOM

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to use reduce on an array of objects to produce a number: `{{ (unit.activeLease$ | async)?.openReceivables.reduce( (sum, receivable) => sum + receivable.balance, 0) | currency:'USD'}}`
but in the developer tools I'm getting an error `Parser Error: Missing expected )` pointing to the beginning of the statement. Am I not allowed to have functions inside?

Comment: You can try this: define `const reducer = (sum, receivable) => sum + receivable.balance` in the component class, and call `.reduce(reducer, 0)` in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions aren't allowed in Angular component templates; doing the opposite would require `eval` in JIT compilation mode.

Component class is where the code belongs to. In order to be used in template,

```
(sum, receivable) => sum + receivable.balance, 0)
```

function should be defined as component method.

The need for lengthy code in component template indicates that it needs to be refactored. `activeLease$` observable should be pre-processed before exposing it to a template, e.g.:

```
balance$ = activeLease$.map(openReceivables => 
  openReceivables.reduce((sum, receivable) => sum + receivable.balance, 0)
)
```